# How do I set environment variables in Postman from values sent is the request body?

Tags: postman

Okay so I am trying to set the 'user1id' environment variable to value that is in my request POST body. I have tried `pm.environment.set("user1id",pm.request.json()["username"]);`

`pm.environment.set("user1id", pm.body.json()["username"]);`

and even just `pm.environment.set("user1id", "username");` - This last one just sets the environment variable to username and that actually value of username that I am sending in the POST request. Surely there must be a way to do this?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you're just trying to capture the values from the request body, you can use this:

```
let req = JSON.parse(pm.request.body.raw);
pm.environment.set("Username", req.username);
pm.environment.set("Password", req.password);
```